# Android cgi web server write files and loading perl scripts

Tags: android, perl, cgi, webserver, sl4a

I want to be able to run a cgi application on my samsung galaxy tablet running android 3.2.
I have installed GroomDroid, SL4A, and PerlForAndroid.
I put my groom.conf file in my /sdcard directory and start GroomDroid.

I put my perl scripts in the /data/perlapp folder and make the perl files executable and make the parent folder writable.

All the files are doing is running print statements.  When I access the perl scripts life is good.  I see the web page as expected just like I would on a computer.

Now if I try to create files from the perl scripts I am getting HTTP 506 IO Error.

Any ideas why I would be getting this?

I call cannot get a require statement to work even if the perl files are in the same directory.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

---

The code I am trying to run:

```
#!/data/data/com.googlecode.perlforandroid/files/perl/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\""; 
print "<html><body style=\"font-family: arial; margin: 20px;\"><span style=\"color:red; font-weight: bold; padding-right: 10px;\">"; 

eval { 
    open(FILE, ">>/data/scwi/data/temp.cgi") or print $!;
    print FILE "respondent 1\n";
    close(FILE); 
}; 
print $!; 
if ($!) { 
    print "Error"; 
} else {
    print "Success";
} 
print "</span></body></html>";
```

Comment: Are you checking the return values of your system calls (`open`, etc.)? Are you checking the value of `$!` (and maybe `$^E`)?

Comment: I have the open statement in an eval block and I am checking $@ afterwards.  $@ is empty.

Comment: All that proves is that your open statement is valid syntax, not that it succeeded. Check the return value, and check `$!`.

Comment: It returns 'Not a typewriter'  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Here is the perl script.
#!/data/data/com.googlecode.perlforandroid/files/perl/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"         \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"";
print "<html><body style=\"font-family: arial; margin: 20px;\"><span            style=\"color:red; font-weight: bold; padding-right: 10px;\">";
eval
{
open(FILE, ">>/data/scwi/data/temp.cgi") or print $!;
print FILE "respondent 1\n";
close(FILE);
};
print $!;
if ($!)
{
print "Error";
}
else
{
print "Success";
}
print "</span></body></html>";

Comment: [Not_a_typewriter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_a_typewriter)

Comment: I remove the write to file stuff and try to print and I am still getting HTTP 506 IO Error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Solved by editing groom config.

place scipts in cgi-bin folder on the scard.

make sure the script extension cgi or pl is listed in groom config and both are dealt with by groomcgihandler, also make sure `groom.conf` has `scard/cgi-bin` as the host directory i.e localhost:8080 will actually point straight to `scard/cgi-bin`

Answer (score 0):

You try to write a file in the /data/ directory.

Are you sure you have the access to write in this directory?

- First, try to write in the /sdcard/ directory, it is world writable.
- Then check if you enough right to write in the directory using the stat() function